# VS Code command + d copy and pasting instead of highlighting/mass editing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use command + d to highlight all matching occurrences in my code and edit them at the same time. Just today, I was trying to use this command and it no longer does that for me. Now it automatically copy and pastes whatever I highlight.

Does anyone know how to make command + d work to mass edit all occurrences of the highlighted portion of code?

Comment: Search in your "Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts" for `Add Selection to Next Find Match`.  What is it bound to?  Did some extension remove the keybinding?

Comment: Ah it worked! I had `Add Selection to Next Find Match` listed twice. First instance was set to command d but the second instance was set to ^ g. Thank you!